# Call multi-table SQL query from Excel without a sproc

Tags: t-sql, excel

I have a complex SQL query that joins multiple tables. Here's a watered down version...

```
DECLARE @AreaPath varchar(128)
DECLARE @IterationPath varchar(256)

SELECT 
  [Scenario Id],
  scenarios.[Feature Id],
  [Task Id],
  [AreaPath],
  [IterationPath]
FROM
    (SELECT 
      [SourceWorkItemID] as [Scenario Id],
      [TargetWorkItemID] as [Feature Id],
      [LinkName]
    FROM [TFS_Warehouse].[dbo].[FactWorkItemLinkHistory] as hist
    JOIN TFS_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItemLinkType as links
      ON hist.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = links.WorkItemLinkTypeSK
    Where [LinkName] = 'Feature Link') as scenarios
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
      [SourceWorkItemID] as [Feature Id],
      [TargetWorkItemID] as [Task Id],
      [LinkName]
    FROM [TFS_Warehouse].[dbo].[FactWorkItemLinkHistory] as hist
    JOIN TFS_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItemLinkType as links
      ON hist.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = links.WorkItemLinkTypeSK
    Where [LinkName] = 'Child') as tasks
  ON scenarios.[Feature Id] = tasks.[Feature Id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN TFS_Warehouse.dbo.CurrentWorkItemView as workItem
  ON tasks.[Task Id] = workItem.System_Id
WHERE [IterationPath] = @IterationPath
  AND [AreaPath] = @AreaPath
ORDER BY [Scenario Id], scenarios.[Feature Id], tasks.[Task Id]
```

I would like to call this query from an excel spreadsheet, but I don't have permissions to add a sproc to the database I'm querying. I'd also like to be able to set values for AreaPath and IterationPath from the spreadsheet.

Is it possible to call this query from Excel? If not, what's a good way to execute this query and import the output of the query into Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your query is indeed a single query (as opposed to several SQL statements), then you can play a trick:

Create a normal Excel query table that points to the right data source and includes required number of parameters, but selects something irrelevant (such as `select 1,2,3,4,5 from existing_table where existing_field = [param1] and existing_field = [param2]`).
You now have a template query with two parameters. Accociate these with cells on the sheet.

Now, select a cell within the template query results and execute this command:

```
activecell.querytable.commandtext = "sql text"
```

In `sql text`, replace paramters with `?`. No `declare`s or variables, just a `select`.  Parameters are going to be referred to by position, not by name. That means, if the same parameter is used multiple times in the query, they are different parameters and must be added separately to the template.

You know have a working query table that will accept parameters and at the same time execute a complex query that "cannot be represented graphically."

The point is, Excel can run a complex query with parameters, it's Microsoft Query that can't cope with it.

Note that an attempt to edit this query table with Microsoft Query will ruin it. You might want to save your SQL somewhere else in case you do that absentmindedly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call the query from Excel.  There are a number a different ways, I'd look up ADO and Excel to get the syntax.  It would be easy to have cells where the values are, read them, and add them as parameters, either directly or using dynamic SQL.

[Here's an article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819) to get you started.